# Rewrite condition to check if not two URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm forcing a URL change if the user has accessed the site via http://mysite or http://www.mysite

However currently I only check that the site does not equal the main sub-domain which is http://store

I also have another sub-domain but this is being overwritten as well, so I need to change the way my current code works which is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^store\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://store.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would prefer to have it check if the url is either of these:

```
http://mysite.com
http://www.mysite.com
```

...and then apply the rewrite rule, how do I change my Rewrite condition to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one -- works just fine here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mysite\.com|www\.mysite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://store.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

- Here I have placed 2 domain names in single condition using regex pattern.
- I have also modified RewriteRule a bit (that's how I preferring doing it).
- You may also want to add `QSA` flag here since it is 301 redirect (depends on your actual URLs) -- `[R=301,QSA,L]`.

Other approaches:

1) Separate condition for each domain name (need to specify that `OR` logic needs to be used instead of default `AND`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://store.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

2) The same as above .. but using plain text comparison instead of regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mysite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://store.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I have done this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://store.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can any improvements be made upon this?

Actually the first RewriteCond isn't detecting http://mysite.com

Comment: Your current rule makes no much sense to me -- it says: If domain name contains `mysite.com` AND at the same contains `www.mysite.com` then redirect. First condition (the way how you wrote them) should cover second one.

Comment: The first way I wrote them in the question makes all sub-domains change to `store.mysite.com`. I need the ability to have other sub-domains as well, but only change `http://www.mysite` and `http://mysite` to use the `store.` sub-domain